# BLE gatttool interactive shell script

Tags: bash, shell, ubuntu, bluetooth, gatt

I established a connection with a BLE device using gatttool. First I connected to the device with `sudo gatttool -t random -b FF:3C:8F:22:C9:C8 -I` and `connect`. After that I read the value of specific characteristic with `char-read-uuid 2d30c082-f39f-4ce6-923f-3484ea480596`.

[image: Here is a view on the console]

What I want to do is to automate the whole process and put the latter command (querying for value) in the loop, ideally saving each value (appending) to a text file. I tried something like

```
sudo gatttool -t random -b FF:3C:8F:22:C9:C8 -I <<EOF
connect
while[ 1 ]; do
char-read-uuid 2d30c082-f39f-4ce6-923f-3484ea480596 > output.txt
done
exit 1
EOF
```

but it does not help, since I am not even able to connect to the device (ideally there should be some delay between the first and the second command). Also after connecting, an interactive mode is enabled and the shell commands do not work there. I'd appreciate any clues on how to tackle this issue.

Comment: I'd suggest looking into [coprocesses](http://wiki.bash-hackers.org/syntax/keywords/coproc) if you want to stick to bash builtins. Otherwise, the `EXEC:` form of `socat` can be an easy way to launch a script with its stdin and stdout attached to the input and output of another command, if you're looking to make things as simple as possible.

Comment: ...that said, a lot of details depend on... well... *details*, like whether `gattool` writes prompts to stderr or stdout.

Comment: Allright, will take a look at these. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If `gattool` writes prompts to stdout (and doesn't suppress them given non-TTY file descriptors), consider something like:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash
case $BASH_VERSION in ''|[123].*|4.0.*) echo "ERROR: bash 4.1 or newer required" >&2; exit 1;; esac

exec {output_fd}>output.txt

prompt_re='[>] '
capture_re='^handle:.*value:.*$'

wait_for_prompt() {
  IFS= read -r line || return
  while ! [[ $line =~ $prompt_re ]]; do
    [[ $line =~ $capture_re ]] && printf '%s\n' "$line" >&$output_fd
    IFS= read -r line || return
  done
}

wait_for_prompt
echo connect
while wait_for_prompt; do
  echo "char-read-uuid 2d30c082-f39f-4ce6-923f-3484ea480596"
done
```

...saved as `yourscript`, and invoked using `socat` as:

```
socat 'SYSTEM:sudo gatttool -t random -b FF:3C:8F:22:C9:C8 -I 2>&1' 'EXEC:./yourscript'
```

(assuming that `sudo` is configured to work without a TTY; otherwise, you might move it to be `sudo socat`).

Comment: Thank you very much for your prompt response. I tried your solution but I keep getting an error 
`2018/06/28 21:11:05 socat[13878] E waitpid(): child 13879 exited with status 1`
Before trying to look for possible causes of the error, I would like to ask you if you think the "Expect" (https://core.tcl.tk/expect/index) tool might prove useful in my case? I found some people recommending it for such purposes.

Comment: *shrug*. expect isn't a bash tool -- it's a completely different language (TCL), so the bash tag is the wrong place to talk about it. Personally, I much prefer Python -- so I'd use [`pexpect`](https://pexpect.readthedocs.io/en/stable/) -- or even bash, for which [EmPTY](http://empty.sf.net/) is the closer-to-native tool. If you're targeting anything like an embedded system, installing a TCL interpreter to drive a script is in swatting-a-fly-with-a-sledgehammer territory.

Comment: As for the error you're getting, I can't really say anything useful without being able to run `gatttool` myself, sadly. You might try the avenues of debugging I already suggested (like making sure that your local `sudo` configuration works in the no-TTY scenario at hand, or running the whole thing with escalated privileges to be able to remove it). Note that content written to stderr by either program will be visible on the terminal, so there's plenty of room for logging on that end.

Comment: Thank you, I really appreciate your insight! It seems like `pexpect` is exactly what I need here.

Answer (score 1):

Indeed, `pexpect` works fine here. You can find my solution below. The code reads the value of the specific UUID, which contains IMU readings (floats).

```
import pexpect
import struct
import time
import sys

IMU_MAC_ADDRESS = "FF:3C:8F:22:C9:C8"
UUID_DATA = "2d30c082-f39f-4ce6-923f-3484ea480596"

if __name__ == '__main__':
    gatt = pexpect.spawn("gatttool -t random -b " + IMU_MAC_ADDRESS + " -I")
    gatt.sendline("connect")
    gatt.expect("Connection successful")

    while(True):
        gatt.sendline("char-read-uuid " + UUID_DATA)
        gatt.expect("handle: 0x0011      value: ")
        gatt.expect(" \r\n")
        data = (gatt.before).decode('UTF-8').replace(" ", "").decode('hex')
        print(struct.unpack('f', data)[0]
```